# Laravel Many to Many relation

Tags: laravel-4

I getting started with Eloquent, and I've ran into a problem. I trying to setup a many to many relation schema + model.

Here is the code:

```
routes.php snippet:
$user1 = User::findOrFail(1);
$user2 = User::where('username', '=', 'TestUser')->get();
// we make $user1 to follow $user2
$user1->followedBy()->save($user2);
```

User model snippet:

```
public function followedBy() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_follows', 'user_id', 'follow_id');
}

public function following() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_follows', 'follow_id', 'user_id' );
}
```

DB Schema snippet:

```
Schema::create('user_follows', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('follow_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The error I get when I visit the routes:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Laravel/proj2/app/routes.php on line 84 and defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all:

```
$user2 = User::where('username', '=', 'TestUser')->get();
// returns Collection
```

You need this instead:

```
$user2 = User::where('username', '=', 'TestUser')->first();
// returns single Model
```

---

And by the way:

```
// we make $user1 to follow $user2
$user1->followedBy()->save($user2);
```

it's `$user2` to follow `$user1` and use this:

```
$user1->followedBy()->attach($user2);
```

For `save` is saving the `$user2` model first, what is redundant here. It's used in such cases:

```
$user2 = new User;
// assign some properties
...
$user1->followedBy()->save($user2);
```

Comment: thank you, i did know get() returns all rows where username is matched and first() will return only the first occurrence, but I couldn't figure this out form the exception :)

Comment: The difference is that `get` returns a `Collection` always (it may be empty if no data is found) while `first` returns `Model` or `null` if there is no data.